# Where can I find a dataset containing locations of all USPS post offices?

Tags: data

I searched the USPS web site, queried GeoData.gov, did a general Google search and turned up nothing. I tried querying GNIS for feature type post office, but the data is listed as "entered 1993" for most entries, and just looking at some in my general vicinity I can find now-closed post-offices not listed as "historical", currently open post offices listed as "historical", and open post offices with locations listed as unknown. All in all, not a very good approach.

While a national listing would be ideal, a source for just New Mexico would suffice (at least for now.)

Comment: Would querying open street map do for your purposes?

Comment: The results from the OSM results from the nominatum and GeoNames both appear to have their origins in GNIS, sharing it's faults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USPS has a map showing all postal facilities that are closed or having issues. However, it also shows the offices that are still open!  AFAIK this map isn't mentioned on usps.com anywhere and is probably intended for internal use.

https://uspstools.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=1fc1c26bb31246b39087606c65b83020

The data you're looking for is on layer "USPS DDUs_New" or here: https://uspstools.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a3371e2708714458b6e3e95104339cd8

Comment: After 10+ years an answer - just amazing. There's an error in the URL for the rest service - there's a trailing /0 that doesn't belong there. But once I removed that I got the data I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See the link below the descriptor from UNC GIS data finder

"FSA Postal Centroids   Shapefile   1:50,000    2002    postal codes, forward sortation areas, three-character postal codes, locations, post offices, zip codes"

http://www.lib.unc.edu/reference/gis/datafinder/index.html?search_type=show_category_contents&datalayers=1&category_id=13

Comment: It looks like you intended to include a link, but it's not there.

Comment: If you follow that link to the next screen of description, it's Canadian post offices. Also, the file is restricted to the UNC community, licensed from ESRI. However, the list includes another file with USPS data, also restricted to UNC community, but also from the ESRI data sources, so perhaps it's buried on an ESRI DVD I have. Thanks.

Comment: Please update the link on your post as it is currently outdated.

Answer (score 2):

One possible data source is the POI Factory.  They have a [post offices layer](http://www.poi-factory.com/poifiles/us/post-offices) (I don't know the quality of the data) that purports to have

> "22,411 POI locations in the United States."

Depending on your planned use, you should definitely read their [Terms of Use](http://www.poi-factory.com/terms).

Comment: this also appears to be a re-packaging of GNIS data